# How to lookup object in array with aggregation in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `aggregate([...])` method to select documents from MongoDB, but I have a problem with `$lookup`, I can't get the results of the reference field `info` after query, it not works because it always return empty array. How can i solve this problem ?

My MongoSchema config:

```
const PostModel = new Schema({
  ...,
  info: [
    {
      label: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'catalogs',
        required: true           
      },
      value: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'attributes', 
        required: true           
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
})
```

My code for execute aggregate to query collection:

```
  const doc = await PostModel.aggregate([    
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "catalogs",  
        "localField": "info.label",  
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "infoLabel"
      }
    },           
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "attributes",  
        "localField": "info.value",  
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "infoValue"
      }
    },                  
    {
      "$project": {
        info: {
          label: '$infoLabel',
          value: '$infoValue'
        }
      }
    }  
  ])

  console.log(doc) // it always return empty array :(
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide some sample dataset and expected output

Comment: @ray thanks, i was solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first unwind the info then use lookup query that will work

```
{ $unwind:"$info" },
{ $lookup:{ ... } }
```

Comment: I don't know how to grouping results after using $unwind

Comment: okey, i was solved my problem with `$unwind`. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).